NavigationList ForEach loop from data model
I am having issue with looping through my API call decoded JSON data within a navigation list. I have successfully put the data into a variable and just can't seem to work out how to loop through the data and list in Navigation view. The error I receive is: "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'CompetitionGroup' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"
struct ContentView: View {
    let compse = competitionslist
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                //ERROR ForEach(compse!) { competition in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(competition.genericname)) {
                        Image(systemName: "airplane")
                        Text(competition.genericname)
                    }.padding()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Destinations")
            }
        }
    }
}

The data is decoded as show below:
func  getComps() -> CompetitionGroup? {
    let headers = [
        "x-rapidapi-key": "apices",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "api.webnsite"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://football-web-pages1.p.rapidapi.com/competitions.json?include=rounds")! as URL,
                                            cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let comps = try decoder.decode(CompetitionGroup.self, from: data!)
                self.competitions = comps
            }
            catch {
                print("Error in JSON")
            }
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
    return competitions
}

The CompetitionGroup model holds a list of Competitions model, both models structs are shown below. any help would be appreciated.
public struct CompetitionGroup: Codable {
   var competitions:[Competition]?
}

public struct Competition: Codable {
var id: Int?
var type: String?
var genericname: String?
var fullname: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case genericname = "generic-name"
        case fullname = "full-name"
    }
}


Looks like compse is the top level object which is not a collection, try ForEach(compse!. competitions). Somewhat untreated but why is everything optional in your Codable struct's?

@JoakimDanielson thank you for response, I added that but still same error

You need to unwrap the values first
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        let competitions = compse?.competitions ?? []
        List {
            ForEach(competitions, id: \.id) { competition in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(competition.genericname ?? "")) {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane")
                    Text(competition.genericname ?? "")
                }.padding()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Destinations")
        }
    }
}

Note that NavigationView is deprecated and should be replaced with NavigationStack

Thank you soo much that seems to have sorted the for loop error. only issue is now the competitions variable is nil I assume due to the getComps() method not completing before for loop is ran. any ideas of how to get around that? I have none every time I make progress there's another reason it doesn't work. I hate iOS

Lot of solutions in this question
